# Telling ftpsync to ignore directories in public_html

Tags: node.js

In ftpsync, when I try to update my site example.com, I find ftpsync deletes everything in public_html (where example.com resides). My host specifies that other domains reside as subdirectories in public_html.

Even though I have tried telling ftpsync to ignore `public_html/subdir-example1.com` and the code shown below it gets removed every time I try an update.

```
{
  "local":"public/",
  "remote":"public_html/",
  "host":"example.com",
  "port":21,
  "user":"secret",
  "pass":"secret",
  "connections":"1",
  "ignore":[
    ".htaccess",
    "subdir-example1.com/",
    "subdir-example2.com/"
  ]
}
```

So how do I tell ftpsync to ignore a directory on the host?

Comment: Have you tried doing "subdir-example1.com/**/*", or even "public_html/subdir-example1.com/**/*"

Comment: neither of those work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

ftpsync says it basically nukes the entire directory on the other server. So the workaround is to create a subdirectory in public_html, then change the remote in config.json to be `public_html/subdirectory/maindomain.com`

Then change .htaccess following instructions written by BlueHost:

```
# BlueHost.com 
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347#redirect